# How can I extend a custom class ussing Architect?

Tags: sencha-touch-2, sencha-architect

I'm using Sencha Architect. I have already created a base class called MyApp.view.MyMenu that extends Ext.Menu.

How can I create a second class called: MyApp.view.MySecondMenu that extends MyApp.view.MyMenu. I cannot seem to be able to change the extend property!

Thank you!

PS: I'm using Architect v3.0.4.1386.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found a solution:

1. In the Toolbox search for Class.
2. Drag the Class into the Project Inspector
3. Now you are able to modify the extend property :)

Answer (score 0):

This is a problem in architect I really hate.
You have to add a custom class (you can do via the + in the corner of project Inspector) and there you can set the "extend property" to what you want.
The big disadvantage is that you don't have your properties in the inspector so you have to add every property you need as a custom one.

It's a kind of ugly workaround but the generated code is alright, hopefully they will better this one day.